# redirect user after facebook share and publish

Tags: facebook, button, redirect, share, publish

How can I redirect a user to a specific URL if the user publishes and to a different URL if he skips?

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
app_id=123050457758183&
link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&
picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&
name=Facebook%20Dialogs&
caption=Reference%20Documentation&
description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&
redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response
```

The above example redirects the user to same URL whether he clicks publish or skip.

I tried the example given below:

```
   <script> 
  FB.init({appId: " id", status: true, cookie: true});

  function postToFeed() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      link: 'link to share',
      picture: 'gggg',
      name: 'ggg',
      caption: 'ggg.',
      description: 'ggg.'
    };

    function callback(response) {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post successfully published, Post ID: " +     response['post_id'] + " click here";

var str = "Click here to activate your new timeline facebook profile!";
document.write(str.link("redirection url here"));


 }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }
```

But the above example also is unable to give results.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
FB.init({appId: "YOUR_APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true});
  function share_me() {
    FB.ui({
      method: 'feed',
      app_id: 'YOUR_APP_ID',
      link: 'SHARE_URL',
      picture: 'PIC_URL',
      name: 'SHARE_NAME',
      caption: 'SHARE_CAPTION',
      description: 'SHARE_DESCRIPTION'
    },
    function(response){
      if(response && response.post_id) {
        self.location.href = 'SUCCESS_URL'
      }
      else {
        self.location.href = 'CANCEL_URL'
      }
    });
  }
</script>";
  <div onclick="share_me()">Share</div>
```

A bit different from yours but I hope you get the idea. We're using our own framework so I can't guarantee the FB initialization is correct :(

Comment: Should i replace //successful post with the url i want to redirect the user to?

Comment: yes, you can use self.location.href = 'your_url_here' or top.location.href = 'your_url_here' depending on your needs

Comment: The previous code i was using used to work in html webpage. Sorry if i am asking a noob question...but how to get the above code to work...

Comment: reworked it. It's working 99% :) I'm only not sure on the FB.init because we initialize it in framework and I never use it :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : 'FACEBOOK_APP_ID',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v3.3'
    });
  };
 function share_me(url,productlink) {
 FB.ui({
  method: 'share_open_graph',
      app_id: 'FACEBOOK_APP_ID',
      link: 'REDIRECT_URL',
       action_type: 'og.likes',
  action_properties: JSON.stringify({
    object:
   {
   'og:url': productlink, 
  'og:image': url 
   }
  })
 
}, function(response){
  // Debug response (optional)
  if(response && response.post_id) {
        self.location.href = 'SUCCESS_URL'
      }
      else {
        self.location.href = 'CANCEL_URL'
      }
  
});
 self.location.href = 'REDIRECT_URL'; 
 }
```

```html
<script async defer src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>

<div onclick="share_me()">Share</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&display=popup&href=<?php echo get_permalink($product->id) ;?>&redirect_uri= REDIRECT_URL "><span>Share me</span></a>
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue