# Facebook Like Button not page specific. Workaround or alternatives?

Tags: facebook

This may end up being nothing more than a matter of preference, but I'd like to reach some sort of a consensus if at all possible.

I've got a page on which there a several different items that a user might want to share on Facebook. Were it still 2010, I would simply attach a "Share on Facebook" button to each of these items and have that button draft a corresponding wall post when clicked.  But as we all know, Facebook has chosen to deprecate the share button in favor of the 'Like' button.  Problem is (as far as I know) the Like button is specific to a page.  This poses two problems:

1. I can't attach a different Like button to each of the different items a user might want to share.
2. Since the content on the page is not static, a user clicking the like button might be told that a certain number of people have already liked that item, despite the fact that the other likers in all likelihood (no pun intended) clicked the button for a completely different item.  The fact that the URL remains the same causes trouble.

I recently bought something on Amazon, and was immediately taken to a page where I could Share my purchase on Facebook.  Not Like.  Share.  I clicked the button, and it opened a modal window with a pre-drafted wall post.  Does this mean that Amazon is using the deprecated share button?

Would using the Share button in 2012 be totally out of line?

Comment: Have you considered implementing your own share button that calls FB.ui {method: feed} ?

Comment: I had no idea that even existed!  That's a perfect solution.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find the code needed for implementing a custom Share button.

[redirect user after facebook share and publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368337/redirect-user-after-facebook-share-and-publish/9368566#9368566)

I hope it helps you.

Comment: It'll be really great if you'll provide a short sample code to your answer (from linked question that have answered ;)).