# How can I know if user posted something with share/like button?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sharer

The goal is to know if user actually shared some content and if he did to reward him. It can be either share or like button, doesn't matter.

I did find the `edge.create` event in JS SDK but it's not good enough (as far as I tested), because the event is just after clicking like button, not when he actually posts the info on his wall or timeline.

I need to do it without asking for any permissions, if that's possible. Preferably using JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the code here:
[redirect user after facebook share and publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368337/redirect-user-after-facebook-share-and-publish/9368566#9368566)

The share function

```
FB.ui({
      method: 'feed',
...
```

has a callback which you can use to suit your needs