# redirect user after share facebook

Tags: facebook, redirect, share

i want to redirect users to a specific page after they share on facebook, i have found a good answer here at:

[redirect user after facebook share and publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368337/redirect-user-after-facebook-share-and-publish)

here's the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
FB.init({appId: "YOUR_APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true});
  function share_me() {
    FB.ui({
      method: 'feed',
      app_id: 'YOUR_APP_ID',
      link: 'SHARE_URL',
      picture: 'PIC_URL',
      name: 'SHARE_NAME',
      caption: 'SHARE_CAPTION',
      description: 'SHARE_DESCRIPTION'
    },
    function(response){
      if(response && response.post_id) {
        self.location.href = 'SUCCESS_URL'
      }
      else {
        self.location.href = 'CANCEL_URL'
      }
    });
  }
</script>";
  <div onclick="share_me()">Share</div>
```

but when i used the script ,there's no redirect at all, even if the user click "cancel"
please help me with this as am searching for a method like this since 1 week!

Comment: Log the response to console in your callback function. Use your browser’s JS debugger to step through the code.

Comment: This should work. Have you tried putting an alert before redirection? What browser are you using? Have you tried using self.location.href = 'SUCCESS_URL' on your browser javascript console?

Answer (score 0):

Try using another javascript function for redirecting like window.location = "YOUR_PAGE"