# Pop-Up with info to share a post on FB in squarespace

Tags: javascript, facebook, popup, share, squarespace

Im working on page https://www.djaspirins.com/ in squarespace and in section "Downloads" I have a track that i want to be able to download only when customer has shared a post about this track on their facebook page. So when they click on "download now " , there should be a pop-up window with sharing option. Maybe someone has worked with squarespace pop-ups and have used JavaScript so file could be downloaded only after shared on FB page? Is it even possible in squarespace? I have asked this on squarespace forum, but there is no answer about this, yet.
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way to reliably and securely pay-wall/share-wall content that you upload via Squarespace file manager or content management system. Files uploaded in either of those ways are publicly accessible.

It may be possible to make it *appear* inaccessible and thereby obtain additional shares on Facebook, but you'll likely have to write such a solution yourself; it would surprise me if services exist to help with this, due to the fact that it is not allowed per the [Facebook Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/examples-platform-policy-4.4).

> Don'ts:
>
> X Don't incentivize people to post content on Facebook, or give the impression that posting to Facebook will be rewarded. For example, don’t give people anything in exchange for them posting to Facebook (i.e. don’t give or promise virtual goods, achievements, coupons, discounts, access to content or extra entries in a promotion, if they post content to Facebook).
>
> X Don’t incentivize people to like a Page, or give the impression that liking a Page will be rewarded. See examples above and below.

Do consider that before creating your own solution as well.

Finally, you may instead consider using the [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog), triggered via the download link, with the "URL Redirection" feature set to the file URL or a page (setup within Squarespace) containing a link to the file. Of course, there's no guarantee users won't skip the dialog, but that is consistent with the FB Platform Policy.

You may find additional information on SO via [this or similar searches](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=check%20if%20user%20shared%20on%20facebook), and via these related questions and answers:

- [redirect user after facebook share and publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368337/redirect-user-after-facebook-share-and-publish)
- [Is it possible to add a link to download a file that can only be downloaded by sharing it on Facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130267/is-it-possible-to-add-a-link-to-download-a-file-that-can-only-be-downloaded-by-s/19131177#19131177)